# how to plot faceted pie chart in ggplot

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
 Equipment       Area         Count
    RTG           1            12     
    RTG           2            13
    STS           1            34
    STS           2            33
    RTG           3            22
    STS           3            21
```

I want to draw faceted pie chart with equipment and count nos inside the pie chart.

I am using following code in R

```
ggplot(data = test) + 
geom_bar(aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = Area), 
stat = "identity") +
geom_text(aes(x = "", y = Count, label = count),position = 
position_fill(width=1))+
coord_polar(theta = "y") +
facet_grid(Equipment ~ ., scales = "free")
```

But,it does not produce any graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = Area)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Count), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  facet_grid(Equipment ~ ., scales = "free")
```

[image]