# Facetted Pie Chart ggplot2- Not full, just lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

```
dat <- data.frame(table(total$Name, total$Color))
# adds the Count column
names(dat) <- c("Name","Color","Count")

NAME    COLOR    Count
John    Green    1
Joe     Green    12
Jane    Green    32  
Jill    Green    34
John    Blue     2
Joe     Blue     4
Jane    Blue     23  
Jill    Blue     12
John    Red      4
Joe     Red      42
Jane    Red      36  
Jill    Red      15
```

How would I create a set of faceted pie charts by Name? When I try:

```
e <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Name, fill=Color)) 
e + geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
facet_wrap(~Name) +
coord_polar()
```

It results in pie charts that are just lines. Can anyone identify the errors or offer any solutions?

Comment: You've an error in your code.  Try: `e <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Name, fill = Color))`

Comment: ^apologies, that was just a typo as I was typing it in. :/

Comment: Yes, but the data frame in your questions doesn't have a column called "Pass".  So you'll just get lines.  Set that to an existing column and you'll see a change.

Comment: ^That was also a typo...sorry...same problem persists in my data set. (I had to change variable names and data for privacy purposes)

Comment: I think you might want `x = ""` in `aes()` along with `coord_polar(theta = "y")`.  You can see some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44673506/2461552) that may be close to what you want (although ignore the free scales part).

Comment: @aosmith, that helped very much thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set `x` in `aes` to a static value.  I chose 0.
2. Add `theta` = "y"`to`coord_polar` to tell it which axis to use in angles.
3. Add `scale_fill_identity()` since you've mapped colours directly in your fill value.
4. Added `theme_void()` to get rid of the confusing axes, etc.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(~Name,~Color,~Count,
"John",    "Green",    1,
"Joe" ,   "Green",   12,
"Jane",    "Green",    32, 
"Jill",    "Green",    34,
"John",    "Blue",   2,
"Joe" ,   "Blue",   4,
"Jane",    "Blue",   23,  
"Jill",    "Blue",   12,
"John",    "Red",   4,
"Joe" ,   "Red",   42,
"Jane",    "Red",   36,  
"Jill",    "Red",   15)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x = 0, y = Count, fill=Color)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  facet_wrap(~Name) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: This is fantastic thank you very much. If I use geom_text(aes(label = Count), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +'  to add lables the plots become lines. Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: Because you need `position_fill()` to match the previous `position = "fill"` to properly calculate where the values are positioned in polar space.

Comment: I realized that right after I typed it...Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to help, remember to accept it as an answer if it met your expectations.

Comment: Now, I if I were to want to display the labels but not any 0 values on the charts how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just subset your data. `data = dat[which(dat$Count >0), ]`.